# Include sub query result in select statement in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want subquery result to be part of  main query , is this possible in hive

```
select distinct table1.col1,table1.col2,
calcolumn= 
(select count(table1.newcal) 
                     from   Table 1 table2
                     where  table2.col1 = table1.col1
                            and table2.col2 = table1.col2)
                  from Table 1 table1
```

I see error as below

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:1
> cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'count' in expression
> specification

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit join something like this:

```
select t1.col1,t1.col2, 
       count(distinct case when t2.col1 is not null then t1.newcal else null end) as calcolumn
   from Table 1 t1
        left join table2 t2 on t2.col1 = t1.col1 and  t2.col2 = t1.col2
group by t1.col1,t1.col2
```